# How to use .dockercfg to pull private images with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am attempting to pull private docker images from Docker Hub.

```
Error: image orgname/imagename:latest not found
```

The info I am seeing on the internet...

- http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/images.html#using-a-private-registry
- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/7954

Leads me to believe I should be able to put something like

```
{
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
        "auth": "base64pw==",
        "email": "email@place.com"
    }
}
```

In the kubelet uer's $HOME/.dockercfg and kublet will then authenticate with the container registry before attempting to pull.

This doesn't appear to be working. Am I doing something wrong? Is this still possible?

I am using the vagrant provisioner located in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster

Also: I am aware of the ImagePullSecrets method but am trying to figure out why this isn't working.

Update:

I moved /root/.dockercfg to /.dockercfg and it now appears to be pulling private images.

Comment: This seems to be relevant as well: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/12626

Answer (score 1):

From: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/12717/files

> This function func ReadDockerConfigFile() (cfg DockerConfig, err error) is used to parse config which is stored in:
>
> ```
> GetPreferredDockercfgPath() + "/config.json"
> workingDirPath + "/config.json"
> $HOME/.docker/config.json
> /.docker/config.json
> GetPreferredDockercfgPath() + "/.dockercfg"
> workingDirPath + "/.dockercfg"
> $HOME/.dockercfg
> /.dockercfg
> ```
>
> The first four one are new type of secret, and the last four one are the old type.

This helps explain why moving the file to /.dockercfg fixed your issue, but not why there was an issue in the first place.